# Add a row-level skeleton placeholder during loading for AG-Grid

Tags: ag-grid

I'd like to display a skeleton row/placeholder for rows that haven't loaded in my table. I'm using the Infinite model.

The skeleton will need to occur per cell:

[image]

I found some documentation regarding how to add a loader: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-loading-cell-renderer/

The example however isn't directly relevant to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Can you please post in case if you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the help of `valueGetter` (to know if there is any value in the row) and return a string called `"loading"` if there is no row data present and within the `cellRendererSelector` I am showing the component that is needed for showing the skeleton while loading else `return undefined` to show the default. Do not use `cellRenderer` as you'll end up passing the value in return which will cause performance issue. As `cellRenderer` and `cellRendererSeletor` will run when ever you scroll the grid to view. Also make use of `valueFormatter` for formatting the value.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/scrolling-performance/#if-possible-avoid-cell-renderers